# Recursively find the next section by class name

Tags: jquery, html

I have a block of HTML which put simply contains a series of 'sections' each section contains an button. What I'm trying to do is get the section that the button was clicked from and then get the next section and I just cannot get anywhere near it (!) so the HTML (trimmed down for ease of reading as the div containing the button has loads of markup within it) is the following:

```
<section class="showMe">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
         <a class="reg-next-button">Next</a>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="showMe d-none">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
         <a class="reg-next-button">Next</a>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="showMe d-none">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
         <a class="reg-next-button">Next</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

So when the 'button' is clicked the following script block is fired:

```
$('section .reg-next-button').on(click, function (e) {
    var section = $(this).closest("section"); //This gives me the section that the button was clicked from

    //what I've tried to get the 'next' section all of which have been unsuccessful

    var $next = section.next('.showMe');
    var $next = $(this).next('section');
    var $next = $(this).closest('section').find('showMe');
    var $next = $('section.showMe').nextAll();
    var $next = section.next().find('.showMe');

    //once I've got the 'next section I'll do some stuff with adding/removing classes to make the section shown/hidden

});
```

Could anyone assist please?

Thanks,
C

Comment: Problem is in event name that you used `click` as variable but you should use as string

Comment: @Mohammad given that the OP states their event handler runs, I would assume that's just a typo in the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So `section.next('.showMe')` should work that OP used

Comment: You're right, my bad. This would be a typo in that case, voting to close.

Comment: Hi, but it doesn't work

Comment: section.next('.showMe') doesn't get the next section as the length is always zero

Comment: It does: http://jsfiddle.net/6rd10na9/

Comment: Your right it does in fiddle, just not on actual page I've updated the fiddle so that it's more in line and it does work now I'm completely stumped http://jsfiddle.net/6rd10na9/1/

Comment: Check that any error exist in console?

Comment: nah, no errors just doesn't function the same on live

Comment: Put `alert()` in event handler and check that event fired or not?

Answer (score 1):

once you got current section you will be able to get next section without any input parameters. Here you can find sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1spenw6/).

```
$('section .reg-next-button').on('click', function (e) {
var section = $(this).closest("section");
var $next = section.next();    
alert($next.attr('class'));
```

});